# Set variable value to function result in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

This code:

```
function getId() {
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
echo $uri_segments[3];
}
```

...extracts the url segment from a url. Say my url is "mysite.com/a/b/1234"

The code outputs 1234

I want to populate the below code wih 1234 using the function like this

```
$res = $api->query('bibs/getId();', array(
```

so its the same as

```
$res = $api->query('bibs/1234', array(
```

....but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Do I need to parse or something?
Thanks

Comment: Best off doing $res = $uri_segments[3];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you need to actually *return* the value you want to use of it:

```
function getId() {
   $uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
   $uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
   return $uri_segments[3];
}
```

Then you could output the result,

```
echo getId();
```

or assign it to another variable

```
$id = getId();
```

or use it directly (by concatanating to the other string:

```
$res = $api->query('bibs/'.getId(), array(...

// the same when assigning it to a variable before:
$id = getId();
$res = $api->query('bibs/'.$id, array(...
```

Please see IMSoP's answer for very useful explanations and links!

Comment: You beauty :) ! Thanks. Worked perfect...$res = $api->query('bibs/'.getId(), array(...

Answer (score 2):

The `echo` statement is [described in the manual](http://php.net/echo) as:

> echo — Output one or more strings

By "output", what is meant here is sending the string to the user - displaying it on the terminal of a command-line script, or sending it to the user's web browser.

What you are looking for is to use the value elsewhere in your code, which is known as "returning" the variable. There is [a manual page about returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).

The next thing you need to do is *combine* that value with the fixed string `'bibs/'`. For that you can use either [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) or [string interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
$res = $api->query('bibs/' . getId(), array(
```